# Error: 'observableFactory is not a function' when using 'defer'

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular9

I created an Angular 9 directive that shows an HTMl element only if the user is authenticated:

```
<div *authenticated>
  Message for Members
</div>
```

And the directive code is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[authenticated]'
})

export class AuthenticatedDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor(private template: TemplateRef<any>, private container: ViewContainerRef, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.authenticationService.isSignedIn().subscribe(x => {
      x ? this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template) : this.container.clear();
    });

  }

  ngOnChanges() { 

    this.authenticationService.isSignedIn().pipe(
      distinctUntilChanged()
    ).subscribe(x => {
      x ? this.container.createEmbeddedView(this.template) : this.container.clear();
    });

  }

}
```

When I run the code I get the error:

```
TypeError: observableFactory is not a function. (In 'observableFactory()', 'observableFactory' is an instance of ZoneAwarePromise) — defer.js:8
```

I checked the `authenticationService.isSignedIn()` method and I have:

```
isSignedIn(): Observable<boolean> {

  return defer(this.manager.getUser()).pipe(map((user: User) => !user.expired));

}
```

The method `this.manager.getUser()` returns a `Promise<User>` so I use `defer` to return an `Observable`.

If I change `defer` to `from` then it works ...

But should I not use `defer`?

Comment: Why would you want to use defer in the first place? Do you know what it does?

Comment: The idea I have is that `defer` would only create the observable when the observer subscribes it ... First I had `from` then I started considering `defer` but not being completely sure about it in part because I am 'only' converting the Promise to Observable

Comment: [This](https://netbasal.com/getting-to-know-the-defer-observable-in-rxjs-a16f092d8c09) may help you to understand how defer works and how it should be used.

Answer (score 3):

You're just using `defer()` the wrong way. It takes callback as a parameter that is called every time a new observer subscribes. When you use it as `defer(this.manager.getUser())` it tries to use the return value from `getUser()` as a method which I guess it isn't so it throws an error.

Instead you should use it like this:

```
defer(() => this.manager.getUser())
```

Now every new subscription will call this method and `defer()` will subscribe to it. Whether you should be using it at all I don't know. It depends on what `getUser()` does internally. If it always returns the same Observable then you don't need `defer`. If it returns different Observables (for example makes HTTP request with different params) then you'll need to use `defer()`.

Comment: getUser (https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/3004ff34efa44a83b0ea1bd731be48b710df47d4/src/UserManager.js#L66) gets the User from Storage and returns a Promise<User>